# Haskell Error on program

Tags: haskell

just working on a problem and it keeps giving me this error:
Exception: Prelude.tail: empty list

Here is my code so far:

```
lxP :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]
lxP []   = []
lxP xss 
   | any null xss = []
   | otherwise    = loop xss []
   where loop ::Eq b => [[b]] -> [b] -> [b] 
         loop xss acc =        
               let xs = concatMap (take 1) xss
               in if any (\x -> x /= head xs) (tail xs)       
                     then reverse acc
                     else loop (map tail xss) (head xs : acc)
```

Any idea if my indentation is the problem or is it something with the code?
PS. How could I improve the efficiency?

Comment: The error message is pretty simple, you're calling tail with an empty list. Step through your algorithm and think what could cause that to occur.

Comment: Iv tried that but i haven't found problem, could you point me what I need to change?

Comment: I'd guess at some point `xs` becomes empty, triggering the error. This is why `head,tail` should be avoided. Sure, you do check `any null xss` at the beginning to prevent that, but this property is not necessarily preserves at each recursive call. (Is your code trying to do something like `concat . transpose`, by the way?)

Comment: By the way, you could try to use the GHCi debugger to see what's going on. https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#debugging-exceptions

Comment: Try `map head . takeWhile ((==1) . length) . map group . transpose`

Answer (score 3):

I can’t quite work out what your function is supposed to do. It doesn’t make sense to me as a reasonable thing to want. Here’s what it looks like to me:

You take some list of lists (let’s say it’s a matrix for now as I’m about to talk about columns) and you want to return the longest prefix of the first row such that each element is in a constant column.

So let’s try to write this in a more idiomatic way.

Now we want to look for constantness in columns, but what should we do if the rows aren’t the same length? I’m going to decide that we’ll just ignore them and imagine shoving all elements upwards so that there are no gaps. Let’s convert rows to columns:

```
transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose xss = t xss where
  n = maximum (map length xss)
  t [] = repeat n []
  t (xs:xss) = join xs (t xss)
  join [] yss = yss
  join (x:xs) (ys:yss) = (x:ys) : join xs yss
```

So now we can write the function.

```
myWeirdFunction xss
  | any null xss = []
  | otherwise = map head $ takeWhile constant $ transpose xss where
    constant (x:xs) = c x xs
    c x (y:ys) | y == x = c x ys
               | True   = False
    c x [] = True
```